# What is the use case difference between modifiable and readonly in vim?

Tags: vim

The first one prevents you from entering insert mode, and the second one prevents you from writing the file.

But functionally speaking, do they achieve anything different?

Comment: You explicitly state the difference between the two modes than ask if there is any difference between them...  Seems like a pretty bizarre way to ask a question!  What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: He is asking what use cases there are, not what the difference in the features are.

Comment: @jahroy, I guess the answerer understood what I was getting at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Modifiable Use Example:

You can save a modified file as a new file.

#### Readonly Use Example:

You wouldn't want to edit a `:help` buffer.